# Coupon collector's clarification

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, coupon-collector

[image]

I would like to know when they say "a little more thought" reveals their answer for $T_{k-1}-T_k$, what is the thought exactly? If $T_2$ is distributed geometrically with probability $\frac{n-1}{n}$, then surely $T_k$ is distributed geometrically with probability $\frac{n-k-1}{n}$ and $T_{k+1}$ is distributed geometrically with probability $\frac{n-k}{n}$? How is it so that they claim $T_{k+1}-T_k$ ddistributed geometrically with probability $\frac{n-k}{n}$?

Comment: $T_{k+1}-T_k$ is the number of cards you have to buy after you have the $k$th distinct card until you have the ${k+1}$st distinct card.  You seem to be interpreting this as $T_{k+1}$

Comment: Yes, I am. I read this as one geometric distribution subtracted from another, am I right? How does this give us the number of cards?

Comment: No, you are not right.  Neither variable is geometrically distributed.  Read the definition again.  $T_k$ is the number of cards we have to buy **in total** until we have $k$ distinct cards.  It is not the number of of cards we have to buy between getting the $k-1$st card and the $k$th card.

Comment: So does this mean that $T_K$ is the sum of $k-1$ previous geometric distributions?

Comment: Yes, except that you mean $k$ geometrically-distributed r.v.'s.  (The first has $p=1$.)

Comment: Ok, so if I was asked to 'find the distribution' of $T_k-T_{k-1}$, how would I do so?

Comment: Then it's a geometric distribution, as described in your post.  There are $n+1-k$ cards you don't have yet, so $$p={n+1-k\over n}$$